# Mysql split string containing different number of words

Tags: mysql, sql, string, split

How can I split strings, which are in one table column, into separate words but those words are not always one and the same number. Sometimes string can contain 1, 2, 3 or more words. And when they are split, to be shown in columns each one of them separately. This is the query so far:

```
SELECT search, count(DISTINCT session_id) IPC, method
FROM table WHERE type='organic'
GROUP BY search, method
```

The one that needs splitting is `search` and after the already generated columns to have others containing the splitted words, everyone of them in separated column.

Will be grateful if someone helps. :)

Comment: It would be easier to understand, if you add sample data and expected output.

Comment: Can't really be done into columns (as that would require a variable number of columns). Best way to split up the strings is to cross join your table against something to get a range of numbers, and then use SUBSTRING_INDEX with that number to get the individual words.

Comment: In general, SQL doesn't allow the number of columns returned by a query to expand based on the data values it finds. The columns in your select-list must be fixed at the time the query is prepared.